# Mysite following feature - custom or not?

Tags: 2013

Do I need to create a mysite for creating a custom following feature ? If yes , when  logs for first time a mysite is created in back end , does it impact for 300000 users ? I have a SharePoint site with docs in doc library and i want to create a custom webpart with follow docs feature of SharePoint . so I realized to create a mysite in order to make my webpart working with the docs followed. Question is : I have 300000 users accessing the site . suppose a user logs in for first time and tries to follow a document . will there be any performance issues ? Because once a user tries to follow a document I think a my site is immediately created in back end .  or what is the best approach for these number of users ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to develop a custom following feature, you don't have to use MySite. You can have a database outside of SharePoint databases which isn't governed by ConfigDB. I guess you have good reasons to do so.

The users MySite isn't created when the user signs in to SharePoint for the first time. It's created when the user clicks her name and when she access MySite for the first time. For 300'000 users all allowed to have a MySite will greatly affect storage in the database. But it depends on how much storage you allow users to have. If you want to allow 20 MB of storage quota for you users, and having MySite Content database limit of 100 GB, you will need 60 Content databases. That's 6 TB on your database server for MySite only.

See: [Scaling MtSite, How many Content DBs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2008/04/14/scaling-mysites-how-many-mysites-per-content-db.aspx)

Comment: Let me explain : The user will follow a document . I am creating code just to pull the documents followed by user . Will i need a mysite for this requiremnt ?